# I need help in calling watcher in Vuejs2 when looping the objects in HTML

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, watch

I am adding one object when clicking on button and displaying the same in HTML. User can able to select the drop down values in options (string or number). Based on the input, need to disable or enable the next text input field. Here is my HTML code,

```
<table>
<tr><button @click="add_new_input()">Add </button></tr>
<tr v-for="(key, index) in NewArr" v-bind:key=value>
    <td>
        <multiselect
            v-model="key.name"
            :options="NameList"
            selectLabel='select'
            @input="userInput(value)"
        ></multiselect>
    </td>
    <td class="modify-td-padding__multi">
        <input type="text"
        v-model="key.value"
        :disabled="isNumber"
        class="input-increase-height">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

if we change the key.name dropdown, it will call one function userInput() using @input. passing value will be either "string" or "number". Vue Mehods is below,

```
userInput: function (value) {
    this.getInputType(value);
},
getInputType: function (value) {
    if(value === "string") {
    this.isNumber = false;
} else {
    this.isNumber = true;
}
},
add_new_input: function () {
    let vm = this;
    vm.NewArr.push({
    name: '',
    value: '',
    });

    vm.$set(vm.NewArr, vm.name, vm.value);
}
```

add_new_input will add new object to NewArr, getInputType function will check the value is "string" or "number". If it is "string", text field should be disabled else enabled.

My issue is, if there are two rows, and if i am selecting key.name for 2nd row, it is affecting the first row input field also(key.name for both rows getting enabled or disabled). I need to make change only the specific text field. So, all the text fields becoming disabled even it is "number". 
This is my first project in VueJS. Thanks a lot if anyone helps me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage `isNumber` per key, so not just

```
data() {return {isNumber: false}}
```

But:

```
@input="userInput(key.name, value)"
:disabled="isNumber[key.name]"

data(){ return { isNumber: {} }}
...
onUserInput: function (key, value) {
    this.setIsNumber(key, value);
},
setIsNumber: function (key, value) {
   this.$set(this.isNumber, key, value !== "string");
},
```